# Preserve absent label values when grouping time series

Tags: prometheus, promql

Let's say I have two metrics: `metric1` with the following series

```
{a='1'} 10
{a='2'} 11
```

and metric `metric2` with the following series:

```
{a='1'} 12
```

If I run query `sum(metric1) by(a) + on(a) sum(metric2) by (a)`, then it returns only
`{a='1'} 22`, but I'd like to preserve the one with `{a='2'}` and just add 0 to it. Is it somehow possible?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following query:

```
(sum(metric1) by (a) + sum(metric2) by (a))
  or
sum(metric1) by (a)
  or
sum(metric2) by (a)
```

Another solution is to use the following query:

```
sum({__name__=~"metric1|metric2"}) by (a)
```